# Select latest document after grouping them by a field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I got a question that I would expect to be pretty simple, but I cannot figure it out. What I want to do is this:

- Find all documents in a collection and:

  - sort the documents by a certain date field
  - apply `distinct` on one of its other fields, **but return the whole document**

Best shown in an example.

#### This is a mock input:

```
[
  {
    "commandName" : "migration_a",
    "executionDate" : ISODate("1998-11-04T18:46:14.000Z")
  },
  {
    "commandName" : "migration_a",
    "executionDate" : ISODate("1970-05-09T20:16:37.000Z")
  },
  {
    "commandName" : "migration_a",
    "executionDate" : ISODate("2005-11-08T11:58:52.000Z")
  },
  {
    "commandName" : "migration_b",
    "executionDate" : ISODate("2016-06-02T19:48:34.000Z")
  }
]
```

#### The expected output is:

```
[
  {
    "commandName" : "migration_a",
    "executionDate" : ISODate("2005-11-08T11:58:52.000Z")
  },
  {
    "commandName" : "migration_b",
    "executionDate" : ISODate("2016-06-02T19:48:34.000Z")
  }
]
```

Or, in other words:

- Group the input data by the `commandName` field
- *Inside each group* sort the documents
- Return the newest document *from each group*

---

My attempts to write this query have failed:

- The `distinct()` function will only return the value of the field I am distinct-ing on, not the whole document. That makes it unsuitable for my case.
- Tried writing an `aggregate` query, but ran into an issue of how to sort-and-select a single document from inside of each group? The `sort` aggreation stage will sort the `groups` among one other, which is not what I want.

I am not too well-versed in Mongo and this is where I hit a wall. Any ideas on how to continue?

---

For reference, this is the work-in-progress aggregation query I am trying to expand on:

```
db.getCollection('some_collection').aggregate([
{ $group: { '_id': '$commandName', 'docs': {$addToSet: '$$ROOT'} } }, 
{ $sort: {'_id.docs.???': 1}}
])
```

---

**Post-resolved edit**

Thank you for the answers. I got what I needed. For future reference, this is the full query that will do what was requested *and also return a list of the filtered documents, not groups*.

```
db.getCollection('some_collection').aggregate([
{ $sort: {'executionDate': 1}},
{ $group: { '_id': '$commandName', 'result': { $last: '$$ROOT'} } },
{ $replaceRoot: {newRoot: '$result'} }
])
```

The query result *without* the `$replaceRoot` stage would be:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "migration_a",
    "result": {
      "commandName" : "migration_a",
      "executionDate" : ISODate("2005-11-08T11:58:52.000Z")
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "migration_b",
    "result": {
      "commandName" : "migration_b",
      "executionDate" : ISODate("2016-06-02T19:48:34.000Z")
    }
  }
]
```

The outer `_id` and `_result` are just "group-wrappers" around the actual document I want, which is nested under the `result` key. Moving the nested document to the root of the result is done using the `$replaceRoot` stage. The query result when using that stage is:

```
[
  {
    "commandName" : "migration_a",
    "executionDate" : ISODate("2005-11-08T11:58:52.000Z")
  },
  {
    "commandName" : "migration_b",
    "executionDate" : ISODate("2016-06-02T19:48:34.000Z")
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
db.getCollection('some_collection').aggregate([
 { $sort: {'executionDate': -1}},
 { $group: { '_id': '$commandName', 'doc': {$first: '$$ROOT'} } }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will result in what you're looking for:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$commandName",
      "executionDate": {
        "$last": "$executionDate"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You can check it out [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/c1YkMu1aivV)

Of course, if you want to match your expected output exactly, you can add a sort (this may not be necessary since your goal is to simply return the newest document from each group):

```
{
 $sort: {
  "executionDate": 1
 }
}
```

You can check this version out [here.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BAnzAi9rzI6)

Answer (score 1):

The use-case the question presents is nearly covered in the [**`$last`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) **aggregation** operator documentation.

**Which summarises:**

> the `$group` stage should follow a `$sort` stage to have the input
>   documents in a defined order. Since `$last` simply picks the last
>   document from a group.

**Query:** [Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yWsNUa3OaYC)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: {
      executionDate: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$commandName",
      executionDate: {
        $last: "$executionDate"
      }
    }
  }
]);
```